# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^{b_n}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges and $a_n\geq0$ and $b_n\geq 1$ for each $n$ then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^{b_n}$ converges.

I know I need to use absolutely convergent but I am unsure how to do it.

Comment: You could start by noting that eventually $a_n \lt 1$ (why?), and use a comparison test.

Comment: @TobErnack You beat me to it! Who cares that it was by 7 minutes... I coulda been a contender!

Answer (score 2):

Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n < \infty$, hence we have $\underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} a_n \to 0$.

Thus, $\exists k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n > k, a_n < 1$

Define:
$$
\begin{align}
A_k := \sum_{n=1}^k a_n^{b_n} < \infty
\end{align}
$$
Then, since we have:
$$
\begin{align}
A_{k'} := 
\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty a_n^{b_n} \leq \sum_{n=k+1}^\infty a_n
< \infty 
\end{align}
$$
Thus we obtain:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^{b_n} = A_k + A_{k'} < \infty
$$

Comment: Your solution is correct. I just want to make notice of the following: the condition $a_n \to 0$ is true for any convergent series.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you!

Comment: Removed the part about absolute convergence - its unnecessary

Comment: (+1) Well written.

Answer (score 0):

**Abridged proof.** The convergence of the series $(a_n)$ guarantees $a_n \to 0,$ hence $(a_n^{b_n})$ is also a convergent series given the assumptions $b_n \geq 1.$ Q.E.D.